# how would one design a wand for this magic system?

Tags: magic, tools

I've designed a magic system and im wanting to make wands for it. it has eight different types of magic: lux, pyr, hydr, aero, necrom, terra, prestia, and bizarre.

The first six are known as the hexachromal magics, each being associated with color and the magics are attracted to those with the most similar colors and repelled by those that are the most different. Pyr is orange, hydr is blue, terra is green, lux is yellow, aero is red, and necrom is purple. There are also certain metals that interact with these magics, known as magimetals. Each one is associated with a particular magic and is attract strongly to it and repelled by the complementary color, with no interaction with those in between. gold has the property of being attractive to magic up to a point and then repulsive, making magic float above it in currents that move in a similar way to electricity. other conductors can have similar effects, but to a much lesser degree, and with a much more unstable equilibrium.

Prestia and bizarre are a pair, strongly attracted to one another, but their magimetals are strongly repelled to the opposite magic and attracted to the opposite metal. The magics, in turn, are strongly repelled by each other's metals.

Magimetals all weigh 45 kilograms per cubic meter at 0 degrees Celsius, and all the hexachromic magics are 0.04 kilograms per cubic meter under the same circumstances, with prestia and bizarre being 0.07.

Spells work by making the magic vibrate at a certain frequency, which directly correlates to its temperature, and use crystalline minerals that focus corresponding magics into a certain range of frequencies or temperatures. When magics that dont correspond to a focus are sent through, their frequencies are forced further away. The lower the frequency the magic moves at, the more 'sluggish' it becomes while inactive, so if you were to decrease the frequency of magic enough, it would act almost like a liquid, and be very cold due to frequency corresponding to heat. In a way, the higher the frequency, the more magic acts like a wave in a vacuum.

would it be possible to design a wand for this magic system? if so, how would you design it and what would be its limitations in spell casting? would it be widespread? i imagine it to have a sort of trigger for releasing magic and have some way to reload and swap spells. the wand must be able to do magic with minimal reliance on the caster, be consistently reusable, and be capable of more than two spells with as little modification to the wand as possible. it doesnt matter if it can cast more than one magic type, just that it can cast more than two spells.

Comment: What does a "wand" do? Enable someone to cast spells? Store a single-use spell? Enhance a user's natural ability?

Comment: in this context a wand permits non magical people(or people who have a limited natural ability for spellcasting, aka, general population) to have a reusable way to cast spells, as well as switch between spells being used.

Comment: Please put the relevant info in the question itself. We cannot bounce back and forth to retrieve information. https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8202/30492

Comment: How do you cast a spell? How does moving magic around result in spells? for that matter, what is a spell? what can it do?

Comment: a spell is caused by magic that is currently moving and vibrating at a certain frequency being halted with minimal change to the frequency. the frequency the magic moves at decides the spells and its effect. spells are caused by the interaction of mass with the magic, and casting spells is done by releasing magic in a set direction and frequency, and the ways to change frequency are: send it through a focus of corresponding frequency or vibrate the magic at a certain frequency.

Comment: Welcome to the site, zackit. Please note that you can notify one user per comment via the '@<username>' syntax.

Comment: This seems entirely up to you as the author.

Comment: @John ah yes, the final design is my decision, but im wanting to keep this project as logically consistent as possible, and that requires a wand design that can make sense within the magic system, instead of the answer of not telling anyone how wands work.

Comment: @zackit a good rule of thumb for fantasy is to ask these questions: is it relevant?, is it necessary?, does it add something important?.   For reference, you probably don't know how or why Gandalf's staff in Lord of the Rings works but, you know that it is probably powerful.

Comment: ...so, what happens when this magic is released? Are spells usually very simple, such as "heat up the air in front of the caster", or can they be more complex, like "Turn this peasant into a newt"?

Comment: @Globin347 there's a range of effects. the different types of magic (generally) deal with specific elements of the periodic table. pyr is oxygen, hydr is hydrogen, aero is nitrogen, etc, but at high enough frequencies they can have more complex effects or even affect elements that they dont normally, such as terra, which normally works with iron, can affect sodium or calcium at higher frequencies.

Comment: Sounds to me like your wands will be less like clasical magic wands and more like magic computers. Early wands will probably be built to cast one spell and one spell only, while more advanced wands will have switches that move gold circuitry around to create different effects when triggered. Also, when it comes to more advanced spells, wizards will probably also use wands, because the many details of how to channel different magical energies into the right spot will be too complicated for a human to remember, even if they're theoretically capable of producing the effect themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Design it the same way one would design a portable console.

A wand first and foremost should be modular. There needs to be a solid non-magical base (so no cross contamination) with a lot of shielding for the core swappable components (in this case spells).

Spells should be composed in the same generic fashion with different "models" for different levels of spellcasting. The closer you get to a standardized approach the better it is for everyone. Spells should be pre-packaged with their magi-metals and spell focusing components.

Law enforcement and other users should very quickly be able to determine the level of the spell based on how big/complicated your wand is. Pulling out a level 1 Jacket Cleaning wand will look a lot different than the level 9 Apocalypse wand.

The modular nature allows for swapping of spells, a single moddable core wand, and the specifics of magi-metals can be handled by professionals.

Addendum: Naturally occurring foci.

Given naturally occurring foci exist, not just anyone could proficiently attach it to a wand. The magical people have worked for generations on learning how to tune and control these forces (via magi-metal, vibrations, etc.). A layperson could create a wand with these as a core but, they are highly volatile and not something you would want to do day-to-day without training or good health insurance.

"a wand permits non magical people(or people who have a limited natural ability for spellcasting, aka, general population) to have a reusable way to cast spells, as well as switch between spells being used." The mages would know how to create spells as well as collect the proper natural foci. How else would they cheaply make wands! The especially potent ones they would naturally keep.

Additionally, if you can't properly feel magic you can't identify natural foci compared to normal quartz rocks. You can't make normal quartz rocks attune to magic without being able to use it either. So natural foci exist and are used but, they are dangerous unless prepared by a mage.

Comment: what about finding raw, naturally occuring focuses, that havent been tuned? how would law enforcement prevent people from using them assuming they're about as common as quartz? theres nothing that really stops people from using them as long as theyll fit the wand.

Comment: also: your statement on making more capable wands look different form less capable wands makes me think that maybe different magic types have a different standard design, so you can visibly recognize what magic a wand can harness and how well.

Comment: @zackit addendum posted

Comment: @zackit wizards use to use a staff because that foci bit at the tip was prone to exploding when used. now that they can reliably make them not explode, wands are all the rage!

Comment: thank you, this sounds reasonable enough that with them being so similar to unrefined quartz in many ways they would be hard to distinguish. still though, i feel like it would be fairly commonplace for people to illegally produce refined focii disguised to look like generic spells.

Comment: all topics with Magic tend to stray into "too story based" and "opinion based" quite often. best of luck.

Comment: that statement about wands becoming more popular makes me think that there may be a sort of magical industrial revolution as people come to better understand the chemistry and physics of magically active substances.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118924/discussion-between-it-alex-and-zackit).